# "Community" edits are often useless and confusing

Tags: discussion

I've seen this happen many times:  A question will show "Community Bot modified 48 mins ago" on the index page, but when I go there I can't find any evidence of an edit to the question.  All the index entry does is waste the user's time.

Is there any reason why some sort of info about the edit can't be made visible, and, if not, can we skip the useless index entry?

Answer (score 9):

I asked about the removal of the "Bumped to the homepage by Community" banner in 2019 and they said no, they won't add it back. (See [Where's the bump notice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340295/323179)) The bump notice is now in the timeline ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/561708/timeline)). A separate request to [change "modified by Community"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247392/323179) to use some other verb was also declined.

Looking at these questions is not supposed to waste your time — you're supposed to evaluate the answers and see if any deserve upvotes or downvotes. Votes on the answers will cause the question to be [ineligible for further bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/323179).

Alternatively, you can [use a search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=*) to only see the newest questions and answers.

---

For the sake of completeness I'll note there are some other reasons that a post might appear to be bumped by Community (namely, anonymous edits and activity from deleted/destroyed users). As a user with 10k+ rep, you can click on "modified [date]" at the top and be taken to the post with the last activity even if it's a deleted answer. Lower rep users can't really do much when there's a deleted answer, but they will still see the post being bumped since everyone sees the same homepage.

Comment: I never knew about the timeline thingie.

Comment: @HotLicks The timeline used to be hidden before. It was only recently that they added a timeline icon under the vote/save icons.

Comment: You seem to be saying that voting on a question's answer will prevent that question from ever being bumped again, but the linked page only says that voting "**will not cause** a question to be bumped". (Or perhaps I missed something?)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It will be ineligible for Community auto-bumps: "The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that".

Comment: Ah, I see now, thanks!

Comment: [Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/273494) *-Shog9*

Comment: Granting, for the sake of argument, that bumping serves a useful purpose, it still seems misleading to say that the bot **modified** the question, if no actual modifying took place, just the bumping (which is what this question was originally about).

Comment: @jsw29 That's also been declined (see edit), but well before the banner was removed. The request could potentially be re-asked but there were other issues brought up.